# How to reduce amount in Contract and not from Account

Tags: solidity, remix, ether

I have a fallback function like this. So I am able to send and increase the amount in "contract address". Assume I sent 2 transactions like 10 and 20, the sum is 30 is successfully shown.

I am very much confused how to reduce the amount of contract address.
I am using Remix and when i try to reduce it is actually reducing from Account adress.
How to choose contract address and reduce amount of contract. Can you please mention a piece of code.

Actually in Remix only 10 Account address are shown but not the contract addresses

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;
contract sendether{

     function receiveEther() payable public{
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract is the only one able to reduce its balance.

You need to add a function in the contract, that function will be able to send  ether to a recipient

```
function rescueETH() public onlyOwner {
   payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

now send a tx that calls `contract.rescueETH()`.